# Controller variable has no value on Force.com site

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites

I have two ways of viewing a VF page.

1. Through my org with a url like this: https://cseo-dev-ed--seo.na35.visual.force.com/apex/SurveyWelcome?id=a004100000D0mqkAAB
2. Through a public force.com site that anyone can view through this url: https://surveytest01-developer-edition.na35.force.com/SEO__SurveyWelcome?id=a004100000D0mqk&cntid=0034100000ds6Ia&souceid=0034100000ds6Ia&soucetype=contact

The problem I'm having is my controller is only returning a value when it's accessing the 1st url. When I go to my public force.com site, the apex controller variable doesn't return anything.

Here is the javascript I run when the page loads

```
<script>
    const images = "{!URLFOR($Resource.img, 'uploads/')}";
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    h.style.backgroundImage = `url(${images}{!NewSurvey.SEO__Background_Image__c})`;
    b.style.backgroundImage = `url(${images}{!NewSurvey.SEO__Background_Image__c})`;
    console.log(`{!NewSurvey.SEO__Background_Image__c}`);
</script>
```

1st url
[image: 1st url]

2nd url
[image: 2nd url]

I'm sure it has something to do with security, but I'm not sure what part of it. My controller for the vf page is public.

Comment: public sites use `Guest User profile`. Have you granted access of the objects/fields your controller is trying to access to that profile?

Comment: I don't see the Guest User Profile when I go to field level security for the field.

Comment: You won't see that there. I think it is related to that issue. Please refer to my answer I am about to post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue appears to be related to the security and permission on site user. Salesforce Sites uses **Guest User** profile to allow access to the public users. You need to provide access of your object and / or fields to that profile in order to let the users see the data. To give permissions,

- Goto Setup
- Type "Sites"
- Select the **site name** (not the URL)
- You will be redirected to Site configuration page
- Select configure site
- Press the **Public Access Settings** button (that will open the Guest User profile)
- check if your object with appropriate fields is present there.

That should be it.